# How to use Windows batch for bicirculation

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

two files 1.txt  2.txt

**1.txt**

```
a2441

b4321

p8763
```

**2.txt**

```
Apple

banana

peach
```

I want to generated content in 12.bat

```
ren  a2441  Apple

ren b4321 banana

ren p8763  peach
```

I try to write like this but failed

```
@echo on

for /f %%a in (1.txt) do (
   for /f %%b in (2.txt ) do ( 
    ren %%a %%b>>12.bat  
      )  
     ) 

pause
```

How can I achieve my desired results? help me,thks

Answer (score 0):

It is not so straightforward. You'll need to skip increasing amount of lines in the inner loop , but because of the `FOR` parsing you'll need additional subroutine call.And if there are empty lined they need to be stripped with findstr for more accurate skipping of the lines. Also skip argument in FOR does not accept `0` so also an if is needed.

```
@echo off

setlocal  ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
set /a s=0
for /f "tokens=* delims=" %%a in (1.txt) do (

   call :inner !s!
   echo ren %%a !second!
   set /a s=s+1


) 
endlocal
pause
exit /b

:inner
set "second="
if %1==0 (
    for /f "tokens=* delims=" %%b in ('findstr /r "[a-zA-Z]" "2.txt"') do ( 
        if not defined second set "second=%%b"
    )
) else (
    for /f "skip=%1 tokens=* delims=" %%b in ('findstr /r "[a-zA-Z]" "2.txt"' ) do ( 
       if not defined second set "second=%%b"
    )
)
```

Comment: tks for your help

Answer (score 0):

The problem with anidated loops is that for each line of the outer file/loop all the lines of the inner file/loop are processed.

One simple solution is to number the lines of both files and only generate the output line when both numbers match. Quick and dirty:

```dos
@echo off
    setlocal enableextensions disabledelayedexpansion

    >"12.bat" (
        for /f "tokens=1,* delims=:" %%a in ('findstr /n "^" 1.txt') do (
        for /f "tokens=1,* delims=:" %%c in ('findstr /n "^" 2.txt') do (
            if %%a==%%c (
                echo ren %%b %%d
            )
        ))
    )
```

This code just uses `findstr` to generate line numbers (`/n`) for each of the input files, and using the `delims` and `tokens` clauses of the `for /f` command to separate them from the original line contents (note: if the lines could start with a colon, more code is needed). If the line number in first file matches the line number in second file the command is echoed (there is a active output redirection to the final file)

Another option is to assign each file to a input stream and to read them using `set /p` operations from each of the streams

```dos
@echo off
    setlocal enableextensions disabledelayedexpansion

    call :processFiles 9<"1.txt" 8<"2.txt" >"12.bat" 
    goto :eof

:processFiles
        <&9 set /p f1= || goto :eof
        <&8 set /p f2= || goto :eof
        echo ren %f1% %f2%
        goto :processFiles
```

In the `call` to the subroutine we assign each file to a stream. Inside the subroutine each stream is read with `set /p` (note: `set /p` can not read lines longer than 1021 characters)